# Changing Thread Task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I know you cannot kill a boost thread, but can you change it's task?

Currently I have an array of 8 threads. When a button is pressed, these threads are assigned a task. The task which they are assigned to do is completely independent of the main thread and the other threads. None of the the threads have to wait or anything like that, so an interruption point is never reach.

What I need is to is, at anytime, change the task that each thread is doing. Is this possible? I have tried looping through the array of threads and changing what each thread object points to to a new one, but of course that doesn't do anything to the old threads.

I know you can interrupt pThreads, but I cannot find a working link to download the library to check it out.

Comment: That's not normally how threads are created. They are defined to have a specific task.

Comment: That's why I asked if it was possible as a work-around for not been able to kill them.

Comment: The code that is running in the thread is the only one that can influence what it is doing next, so you need to add that possibility to your own task objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thread is not some sort of magical object that can be made to do things. It is a separate path of execution through your code. Your code cannot be made to jump arbitrarily around its codebase unless you specifically program it to do so. And even then, it can only be done within the rules of C++ (ie: calling functions).

You cannot kill a `boost::thread` because killing a thread would utterly wreck some of the most fundamental assumptions a programmer makes. You now have to take into account the possibility that the next line doesn't execute for reasons that you can neither predict nor prevent.

This isn't like exception handling, where C++ specifically requires destructors to be called, and you have the ability to catch exceptions and do special cleanup. You're talking about executing one piece of code, then suddenly inserting a call to some random function in the middle of already compiled code. That's not going to work.

If you want to be able to change the "task" of a thread, then you need to build that thread with "tasks" in mind. It needs to check every so often that it hasn't been given a new task, and if it has, then it switches to doing that. You will have to define when this switching is done, and what state the world is in when switching happens.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation. When I say I want to change what the thread is doing, in actual fact I want the thread to continue doing what it is doing, but instead with different parameters. So I think I might be able to work that into the thread.